# Why pwa workbox is not triggered?

Tags: nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm using PWA Nuxt Workbox Module and have problem that it is not triggered every time or it is triggered twice after deployment.

Module is included as plugin and this is code:

[image]

Comment: Hi, code snippets are not allowed as images. Please write it down as text.

Comment: Check its expiration date and if there is already one running (service workers), thanks to your devtools.